# 60VAC measured when light switch is off

Tags: transformer, wiring, lighting

I'm replacing a fluorescent ceiling light with an LED fixture. I removed the entire chassis, ballast, etc, and now I'm just left with the hot/neutral cabling (no ground wire available).

I wanted to verify that the power was off before I started getting too touchy with wires, so I grabbed my multimeter to measure the AC voltage. With the light switch on I measure 120VAC, but with the light switch off I measured about 60VAC. I then flipped the circuit breaker off for the circuit that the light is on, and it measured about 0VAC.

Would 60VAC ever be normal for a switch being "off"? This is an older house, no idea about the quality of the wiring, and I noticed that there is an old doorbell transformer in the basement, if that could possibly explain anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always a parasitic capacitance across the switch and also between wires in conduits. This capacitance is small but if the wires run together in a conduit, it can be enough to let a few µA AC current through.

The internal resistance of the multimeter is very high in voltage mode, but it is not infinite. What it is measuring is the output of a voltage divider, with the parasitic capacitance in the upper leg, and the multimeter input resistance in the lower leg.

If your multimeter has an input resistance of 10 Mohms, a parasitic capacitance in the hundreds of pF across the switch is enough to register 60VAC on the display.

Answer (score 1):

The multimeter is such a weak load that it can measure capacitively coupled voltage. So yes, it sounds normal.